# how can I get access from angular2 project to the "$wakanda" service to retrive data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, wakanda

I've just created a new project in wakanda.io with angular2 and backend.
I created some db entities and now from the client side I just want to retrive data from the db. In order to make this working I need to import somehow the "$wakanda"  service but in angular2 way.
How can I just import that wakanda service component ? 
Is there any angular2-wakanda npm package but I've not found?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Wakanda JavaScript Client - Quickstart](https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-javascript-client/wiki/Quickstart)